# Property of Projection Operator

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, functions, projective-geometry

Let $p: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow X$ be the projection mapping onto $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ compact convex.

I am wondering if
$$ \left( p(x) - p(y) \right)^\top z \leq \left( x -y\right)^\top z $$
for all $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

What I came up with is just $\left( x - p(x)\right)^\top \left( p(x) - z \right) \geq 0$ for all $x,z \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and obviously $\left\| p(x) - p(y) \right\| \leq \left\| x-y\right\|$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. For example, if you project to a singleton $X=\{x_0\}$ then  $\left( p(x) - p(y) \right)^\top z$ is always zero, while $\left( x -y\right)^\top z$ may well be negative. One could try to salvage the inequality with absolute values: 
$$|\left( p(x) - p(y) \right)^\top z| \leq |\left( x -y\right)^\top z| \tag{2}$$
but this one fails as well. For example, in $\mathbb R^2$ let $X$ be the unit disk, $z = (1,0)$, $x=(1,2)$, $y=(1,1)$. The right side of (2) is zero, but the left is not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually what I have is $\left( p(f(x)) - p(f(y)) \right)^\top(x-y) \leq \left( f(x) - f(y)\right)^\top (x-y)$ where $f$ is pseudocontractive. Would you know additional conditions on $f$ such that the inequality holds?